# Clockwise or counter-clockwise loading animation

Tags: animation, loading, lean-ux

Is there any rule for using CW or CCW loading animation?

Does CCW animation means "slow" or "rollback" or something? Or maybe CW direction means going forward, straight direction etc?

UPDATE: due to Renaud's answer I'll mention - I want to display spinner animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that it depends on what you are showing on the loading animation :

if you just  want to show that something is loading without any duration information, a clockwise will tell the user he just have to wait.

but if you actually display an information about how long the loading will last (much better) you can use 1 round of counter-clockwise like a countdown.

Comment: WOW! Never thought about it that way. Many thanks! But will wait for some time for another ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Chrome way, where uploading/sending is a ccw-circle and loading is a cw-circle. I don't believe there is any rule about it though....  just keep it consistent.